# Core Data Query slow

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data, full-text-search

What's the secret to pulling up items that match characters typed into the search bar that react instantaneously? For instance, if I type in a letter "W" in the search bar, all phrases that contain a letter "W" in any character position within the phrase are returned immediately.

So if a database of 20,000 phrases contains 500 phrases with the letter "W", they would appear as soon as the user typed the first character. Then as additional characters are typed, the list would automatically gets shorter.

I can send query's up to a SQL server from the iPhone and get this type of response, however, no matter what we try and taking the suggestions of other users, we still can't get good response time when storing the database locally on the iPhone.

I know that this performance is available, because there are many other apps out there that display results as soon as you start typing.

Please note that this isn't the same as indexing all words in every phrase, as this only will bring up matches where the word starts with the character typed in. In this case, we're looking for characters within words.

Comment: What approach are you trying now? Are you setting the batch size on your fetch request?

Answer (score 1):

I think asynchronous results filtering is the answer. Instead of updating the search results every time the user types a new character, put the db query on a background thread when the first character is typed. If a new character is typed before the query is finished, cancel the old query and start a new one. Finally, you will get to the point where the user stops typing long enough for the query to return. That way, the query itself never blocks the user's typing.

I believe the UISearchDisplayController class offers this type of asynchronous search, though whether you want to use that class or just adopt the asynchronous design pattern from it is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to get away from the database for this, you could use a generalized suffix tree with all the terms in your phrases.  You can build in a suffix tree in linear time and, I believe, use it to find all occurrences of a substring very quickly.  The web has lots of pages about suffix trees and suffix arrays.  Wikipedia is probably a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I have a fun scheme for you. You can build an index of the characters that exist in each phrase via a 32-bit integer. Flip the bits [0-25] to represent the characters (case-insensitive) a-z that exist in the phrase. Build a second bitmap of the query string. Now you can do comparisons via bitwise operations (& and |) to determine matches. This is very fast and believe it or not SQLite actually supports bitwise operations in queries - so you can even use this scheme to go straight to the database. I have working code that does this built into one of our iPhone applications - Alphagram.

Comment: I assume that Al wants to search for substrings, not the individual presence of a set of characters, which is what that bitmask operation sounds like it would do. I'm guessing once the user types 'W', if they follow it up with an 'e' it should match 'Weird' but now 'Where'.

Comment: I was not certain from his explanation. In Alphagram I use the bitmask as an initial filter and do a second pass on the filtered results to determine if there is an exact match.